# Google Query Return Top N results per category

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I have a Google Spreadsheet with several tabs (same columns, split up based on country)

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1I4cS4oNjCFZ7dWF78rBv6cdHkyWHAF8rGoIlt0941aI/edit?usp=sharing

I need to have this data copied to my "Master" sheet where I will return the 3 LATEST entries per country.

I have tried to head down the QUERY/IMPORTRANGE path, but I am stuck at the part where I need to return the latest 3 entries per country. Googling around, I could find mentions of the PARTITION BY clause...but unfortunately Google doesn't allow for its use.

Comment: What have you tried? Please provide a [mre] and explain how your attempt falls short of expectations.

Comment: I've tried to add some additional detail. Please see my original post.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Hi, I've added a copy. of the sheet now

Comment: What exactly do you mean by '3 latest entried per country'? I don't see any data which identifies them as most recent.

Comment: "last 3" based off cell reference. So the lowest 3 entries in each sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY({
 QUERY(GB!A:G, "offset "&COUNTA(GB!A:A)-4, 1);
 QUERY(FR!A:G, "offset "&COUNTA(FR!A:A)-3, 0);
 QUERY(IT!A:G, "offset "&COUNTA(IT!A:A)-3, 0);
 QUERY(DE!A:G, "offset "&COUNTA(DE!A:A)-3, 0)},
 "where Col1 is not null", 1)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: I gave this a try and it didn't give me what I was looking for. In short, I am looking for a way to return the last 3 records from each country tab, in 1 query. It might be that QUERY isn't what I need...

Comment: Thank you for this. That's what I needed.